# Solution For Monitoring and Maintaining App's Size on Disc

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm building an app that makes extensive use of CoreData and a lot of my models have UIImage and NSData properties (for images and videos). Since it's not a great idea to store that data directly into CoreData, I built a file manager class that writes the files into different buckets in the documents directory depends on the context in which was created and media type.

My question now is how do I manage the documents directory? Is there a way to detect how much space the app has used up out of its total allocated space? Additionally, what is the best way to go about cleaning those directories; do I check every time a file is written or only on app launch, ect ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect how much space the app has used up out of its total allocated space?

Apps don't have a limit on total allocated space, they're limited by the amount of space on the device. You can find out how much space you're using for these files by using `NSFileManager` to scan the directories. There are several methods that do this in different ways-- check out `enumeratorAtPath:`, for example. For each file, use a method like `attributesOfItemAtPath:error:` to get the file size.

Better would be to track the file sizes as you create and delete files. Keep a running total, stored in user defaults. When you create a new file, increase it by the amount of new data. When you remove a file, decrease the running total.

> Additionally, what is the best way to go about cleaning those directories; do I check every time a file is written or only on app launch, ect ect.

If these files are local data that's inherently part of the associated Core Data object, the sensible approach is to delete a file when its Core Data object is deleted. The managed object needs the data file, so don't delete the file if you still use the object. That means there must be some way to link the two, but I'm assuming that's already true since you say that these files are used by managed objects somehow.

If the files are something like cached data that's easily re-created or re-downloaded, you should put them in the location returned by `NSTemporaryDirectory()`. Then iOS can delete them when it thinks the space is needed. You can also clear out old files whenever it seems appropriate, by scanning for older files or ones that haven't been used in a while (the details depend on exactly how you use the files).

Comment: Wow this was super helpful. I didn't even know `NSTemporaryDirectory()` existed! The files are pretty much just NSData representations of UIImages and videos, for say a user post or a user group image, that are loosely associated with CoreData objects so I think I'll probably override the delete method in ObjectiveRecord and delete the files when the model gets deleted.

Does this mean there's no size limit that an app can grow to? (theoretically of course)

Comment: The only limit is space available on the device, there's no specific per-app limit.